# Bash script won't work if it's run from gnome files

Tags: bash, gnome

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup /home/user/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_4_API_30 &
```

The script has 755 access and if I try to run it from the Gnome Files option "Run as a Program" it does nothing. Or, at least, I can't see the emulator window showing up if I run it through the context menu but it works if I run the script from the terminal.

[image]

The "Executable as Program" toggle is set so I have no idea what it's going on.

[image]

Comment: What should it do? How are you checking that it did nothing? Try adding `touch /tmp/somefile` before the `nohup` command and seeing if the `/tmp/somefile` file is created. Also change your command to `nohup /home/user/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_4_API_30 2> /tmp/script.log &` and then check if `/tmp/script.log` is created and if any error messages are printed there.

Comment: Finally, please [edit] your question and give us some more detail about what you are doing. The people active here tend to spend more time on the command line so might not know what this "Gnome Files" is or what the "executable" toggle you mention is. I _think_ I remember seeing something like that in some file manager but I don't really know either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @terdon, I can't see the emulator window showing up if I run it through the context menu but it works if I run the script from the terminal.

Comment: @const314159 it looks like you've not asked for a terminal window to open - you've just asked your program to be run